# Tracking of click on x-webkit-speech

Tags: jquery, speech-recognition

I am working on omniture tracking of the microphone icon that appears when you include the following input tag in your html

I am not able to track the click on microphone icon
i tried using

```
$("#abc").on("webkitspeechchange", function (e) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            alert("speech recognition word"+val);
```

This is not working.
Appreciate your help.
Regards,
Parvathy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#abc").on("speechchange webkitspeechchange", function (e) {
     var val = $(this).val();
     alert("speech recognition word"+val);
});
```